# Python list comprehension if item is not included in list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings and I'd like to find the strings that do not contain letters of a given word. I can easily find the items that do match the given word using list comprehension. I am having trouble reversing this process.

```
import sys

userin = sys.argv[1]
word = userin.lower()

cars = ['mercedes', 'bmw', 'ford', 'renault']

result = []
check = set(word)
result = [c for c in cars if any(l in check for l in c)]
print result
```

I thought this could be reversed using:

```
result = [c for c in cars if not(l in check for l in c)]
```

But that does not give the output I'm looking for. 
I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you use set differences?

Comment: the opposite of `any(l in check for l in c)` would be `not any(l in check for l in c)`

Comment: Did you try `result = [c for c in cars if not any(l in check for l in c)]`?

Comment: When you do `set("abc")`, you get `set(['a', 'c', 'b'])` - which could be the cause of your issue. To debug, either use pdb, or print statements to see what the local variables evaluate to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `not` does not do what you think it does there. What you are actually determining is as follows:

```
not(generator expression)
```

Which is the opposite of:

```
bool(generator expression)
```

The boolean value of a generator is always simply 'True' as it's a non-`None` python object, and they are truthy by default unless some special logic applies (such as an empty container, equaling `0`, or being the `False` object). Thus that part of your code simply returns `False` unconditionally.

What you actually meant is this:

```
result = [c for c in cars if not any(l in check for l in c)]
```

But in this case you *would* be better served by using `set` methods:

```
result = [c for c in cars if not check.intersection(c)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse I guess just use the age old if(__) == False

```
result = [c for c in cars if not(l in check for l in c)]
```

to this

```
result = [c for c in cars if any(l in check for l in c) == False]
```

Hope this helps man not too sure if thats whacha need

Edit:
you can also do a not any()